# django custom user model form widgets working only for email and name field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

in my custom user model that is created with  AbstractBaseUser when i try to add widgets which lets me add classes or place holders or input type etc.. it works only for the full_name and email fields but not for password1 and password2

in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a name')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email",max_length=250, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Full name", max_length=150, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    # For checking permissions.
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # For which users are able to view the app (everyone is)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

#i also have another text model which i don't think that is needed
```

in my forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import *


class TextForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ['title','document','requirements','deadline']
        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Title','class':'form-control m-2 mb-4 pb-2'}),
            'deadline' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Deadline','type':'date','class':'form-control m-2 pt-2',
            'id':'opendate'}),
            'requirements' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'requirements','class':'form-control col m-2','rows':'3'}),
            'document' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'document','class':'form-control'}),

        }

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ("full_name","email","password1","password2")
        widgets = {
            'full_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Full name'}),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email'}),
            'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}),
            'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password2'}),

        }


class SigninForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','password')
        widgets = {
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email','class':'form-control'}),
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password','class':'form-control'}),

        }

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if not authenticate(email=email,password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login")
```

in my view.py file

```
def home(request):

    user = request.user

    # for creating posts

    form = TextForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            form.save()
            form = TextForm()

    texts = Text.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    # for signing in

    if request.POST:
        signin_form = SigninForm(request.POST)
        if signin_form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
    else:
        signin_form = SigninForm()
    
    # for signing up

        signup_form = SignupForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            User = signup_form.save()
            full_name = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
            email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)

    context = {'signin_form':signin_form,'signup_form':signup_form,'form': form, 'texts': texts}

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

NB: in the template i rendred them one by one like: {{signup_form.full_name}} , {{signup_form.password1}} etc... and it's working fine in terms of the backend

Comment: Try this :  forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))

Comment: @itjuba thnaks it worked

Comment: From Dz Dev , good for you mate .

Comment: ooh yeah cool..